# JavaScript 'is not a function' - object instance

Tags: javascript

I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: rect.drawIt is not a function

I don't understand why this error happens? I mean i am doing the same as here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

```js
  var context = document.getElementById("canv").getContext("2d");
    
    for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        var rect = new Recta();
        rect.drawIt();
    }
    
    function Recta() {
        this.x1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.width);
        this.y1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.height);
        this.x2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.width);
        this.y2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.height);
        this.x3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.width);
        this.y3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.height);
        this.x4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.width);
        this.y4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.height);
    };
    
    Recta.drawIt = function () {
        context.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
        context.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
        context.stroke();
    
        context.moveTo(this.x2, this.y2);
        context.lineTo(this.x3, this.y3);
        context.stroke();
    
        context.moveTo(this.x3, this.y3);
        context.lineTo(this.x4, this.y4);
        context.stroke();
    
        context.moveTo(this.x4, this.y4);
        context.lineTo(this.x1, this.y1);
        context.stroke();
    };
```

```html
<canvas id="canv"></canvas>
```

Comment: you try calling _drawIt_ before adding it to _Recta.prototype_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First define the `Recta.prototype.drawIt` then use it.

```
 function Recta() {
    this.x1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.width);
    this.y1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.height);
    this.x2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.width);
    this.y2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.height);
    this.x3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.width);
    this.y3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.height);
    this.x4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.width);
    this.y4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * context.canvas.height);
};

Recta.prototype.drawIt = function () {
    context.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
    context.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
    context.stroke();

    context.moveTo(this.x2, this.y2);
    context.lineTo(this.x3, this.y3);
    context.stroke();

    context.moveTo(this.x3, this.y3);
    context.lineTo(this.x4, this.y4);
    context.stroke();

    context.moveTo(this.x4, this.y4);
    context.lineTo(this.x1, this.y1);
    context.stroke();
};

    var context = document.getElementById("canv").getContext("2d");

for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
    var rect = new Recta();
    rect.drawIt();
}
```

Comment: you can define function in any place in file and it would be available, but adding _drawIt_ it more setup property in prototype than defining function

Comment: @Grundy You are right :) However just to give a clear picture I did that. Edited my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Write the below code at the last (after definition of the object)

```
    var context = document.getElementById("canv").getContext("2d");

    for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        var rect = new Recta();
        rect.drawIt();
    }
```